# HTML Documentation generator for .NET

Tags: .net, documentation

I am looking for a good HTML documentation generator for .NET. `Sandcastle` is too complicated and too buggy for my needs and `NDoc` has been dead for ages.

One of my requirements is that it should also handle Code Contracts, which are exposed as extra elements in the XML file emitted by the compiler.

Comment: I wonder if this could be a project suggestion for [code52](http://www.code52.org), though I would imagine it would take longer than a week to get there.

Comment: Looks like everyone is after this, me included.. good question!

Comment: One would think after 10 years, there would at least be more than a handful of tools for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe doxygen is an acceptable option for your needs...check it [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl). It's compatible with C#.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [ForgeDoc](http://www.forgedoc.com), a brand new documentation generator tool for .NET.
Though it does not support Code Contracts, I think it is a good alternative to NDoc and Sandcastle.

Comment: Send me an email and we talk about getting you 
some press coverage on InfoQ. (jonathan@infoq.com)